# Split a string by a plus sign (+) character

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a string in a data frame as: `"(1)+(2)"`

I want to split with delimiter "+" such that I get one element as `(1)` and other as `(2)`, hence preserving the parentheses. I used `strsplit` but it does not preserve the parenthesis.

Comment: Are you sure? `strsplit("(1)+(2)",split="\\+")` gives me `"(1)"` and `"(2)"`...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use

```
strsplit("(1)+(2)", "\\+")
```

or

```
strsplit("(1)+(2)", "+", fixed = TRUE)
```

The idea of using `strsplit("(1)+(2)", "+")` doesn't work since unless specified otherwise, the `split` argument is a regular expression, and the `+` character is special in regex. Other characters that also need extra care are

- `?`
- `*`
- `.`
- `^`
- `$`
- `\`
- `|`
- `{` `}`
- `[` `]`
- `(` `)`

Comment: What about <, >, <=, and >= ?

Comment: @theforestecologist Those aren't special characters, so you don't need to escape them using the backslash `\ `. If the match expression is simple like the one above, you can also use `fixed = TRUE` when in doubt, as long as there isn't any regular expression being used, but rather just literal text.

Answer (score 2):

Below Worked for me:

```
import re

re.split('\\+', 'ABC+CDE')
```

Output:

> ['ABC', 'CDE']

Comment: The question is in the [r] tag.